# How to insert an "—" direclty from my Keyboard without numberpad?

Tags: keyboard, ascii, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, custom-keyboard

I have searched all corners of the internet, yet to find an answer to my simple question:

How to place, **directly from keyboard input**, the Em-Dash "`—`" character onto a code editor such as Notepad++ or Dreamweaver using modern notebooks (such as a dell xps 13" 2015, win10 64bit) without:

- any extended keyboard numbpad, obviously;
- any third party automation scripting softwares;
- any charactermap insertion tools such as windows charactermap

How? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're asking about how to do it in Windows here.

---

I assume you know how you'd do it if you had a numeric keypad (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> if as it seems you are on the 1252 code page).

See also [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard) , in order to use the unicode value (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>) .

---

This is an at least related question: [How to emulate numpad on a PC laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/467709/how-to-emulate-numpad-on-a-pc-laptop)

---

#### Possible solutions:

- Most notebooks do have an hidden "numpad", accessible through the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (see for example https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/the-hidden-numeric-keypad-on-your-laptop/ ).

  I couldn't find out for sure if the Dell XPS 13 specifically does, but it is very likely.

  This [Me and My Dell](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/common/mmd_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) manual (*Using numeric keypad on a laptop*) seems to explain its usage for all Dell laptops.
- Use copy and paste (copy the character from some place and paste in the editor). A clipboard manager might help you if you choose to go this way.
- You might also use some third-party software to have that character emitted when you press a key or shortcut, but I guess that is included in your "*third party automation scripting softwares*" prescription.
- **Use the unicode combination!** I now found out that with that one you can use indifferently both numbers from the keypad and normal ones !
  Unfortunately it still requires the numpad's "plus" (add) key, so you need to be able to type at least that.
  See [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input to learn how to enable the combination, if it is not already enabled.

---

If there indeed exist laptops with no numeric keypad support unfortunately the Windows developers didn't *fully* anticipate for that; it probably wouldn't take much and wouldn't have negative repercussions for Windows to support the insertion via the normal numeric keys (or the normal <kbd>+</kbd> for the Unicode combination), but for now it's not supported (as far as I know).

It would be a bad mistake on the part of the laptops' developers to not include any way to type the numpad keys, though, as they are required by many programs.

Comment: @Sam I now found out that the unicode combination works with the normal numeric keys, I adapted the question correspondingly.

Comment: awesome +1 for your elaborate answer thanks a thousand. Yes I was referring to win10 64bit (updated my question). Now, i have tried all possible combinations with all my fingers, holding `Alt` pressing sequences `+` and `2014`,  or holding `Fn+Alt` then `2014` or right `Alt` but I dont succeed in my modern notebook and i am sure you are right and I am missing something! Can you tell me how you exactly typed the unicode sequence on your notebook using the top row number keys? Thanks a thousand! We are almost there to cracking this!

Comment: @Sam Have you read all the links I posted? In particular, have you tried the dummies.com test?

Comment: @Sam To use the unicode combination you absolutely need to find a way to type the "+" key that's in the numpad section (and then the sequence as I said is: while keeping "Alt" pressed, type the numpad's "+", then "2", "0", "1" and "4" ). Check first if the unicode combination is enabled, by looking if the registry key mentioned in the links above is present.  
Yes, the two "+" keys that are on normal keyboards are different keys and some functions of some software interpret only one of them.

Comment: @Sam To use the other combination you need to find a way to type the numpad's numeric keys; then if the screenshot you posted comes from your computer the combination is: while keeping the "Alt" pressed, type the numpad's keys "0", "1", "5" and "1".

Comment: @Sam I can't help you more than this, you need to ask Dell how, if possible, you type the numpad keys on that model. If it's not possible, bad luck, it's a shitty notebook with a shitty keyboard (not a _modern_ one, as you keep saying). You have to settle on one of the alternative methods.

Comment: Thanks+1 very much for your quick replies! apparently you are right ;) shitty notebook since otherwise I would not ask. But, on no other notebook I have been able to achieve what I can on my standard computer with extended keyboard (alt easy peasy). I clicked on the dummies link but Firefox keeps saying "The owner of www.dummies.com has configured their web site improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this web site." PS I am not able to get the `—` on  my main PC! I get this `Ì` symbol instead!? But I will contact Dell how to get to the `+` key!

Comment: @Sam For dummies.com just change the address to http (http://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/the-hidden-numeric-keypad-on-your-laptop/). The `Ì` symbol means that you're trying the unicode combination either without having it enabled (see 'registry key' above) or using the wrong "+" key or no "+" key at all. Yes do contact Dell (ask them for instructions for all the numpad keys, as you're at it), most notebooks do have some support for them and I would be pretty pissed if a notebook of that price range did not.

Comment: @Sam I don't have much actual experience with this issue really, I'll try with a numpad-less notebook I have at home in the coming days, but it ought to work, just be quite awkward due to the need to use the 'Fn' key and to find the right keys (that are usually marked -not in your case- but in a light color that easily wears out in a few years).

Comment: @Sam I don't know how it ended up for you, anyhow I was mistaken about my notebook, it doesn't have Windows installed and I'm not going to install it just to test this

Comment: Dear @gbr thanks again for your kind raction. Of course one should not install a whole operating system just to put a single character :-) On the other hand... :D It demonstrates the shere frustration that we (users of notebooks especially Dell XPS?) have to face but... Since the use of the Numbpad `+` is impossible on my notebook, I have decided to sell the notebook. Perhaps that is a step further than "just" changing operating systems ;-)  I bought a do it yourself mechanical 60% keyboard (without numbpad) but with programmable keys! I will report back with pictures once I am all setup!

Comment: @Sam So you've been told by Dell that it's impossible?